# React Native VS Code Intellisense for custom components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am having some trouble understanding how to make custom components. I make a simple Text component for myself to get rid of setting fontsize and fontfamily every single time I use a Text.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Colors } from "../assets/Colors"
import { Text as RNText } from 'react-native';

class Text extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <RNText
                {...this.props}
                style={[{
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.text
                }, this.props.style]}>
                {this.props.children}
            </RNText>
        )
    }
}

export default Text;
```

The problem here is when I type my own component `"<Text style={{marginV"` intelliSense doesn't pop autocomplete this to marginVertical. Also when I type `"<Text onPre"` intelliSense also doesn't pop autocomplete this to onPress. I am really excited about making beautiful components but this is so frustrating to use without intellisense. I already tried setting proptypes but it didn't work. Is there any quick solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to define props type bypass `Props` in-class component like this `extends Component<Props> {`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Colors } from "../assets/Colors"
import { Text as RNText, StyleProp, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

type Props = {
    style: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
}

class Text extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <RNText
                {...this.props}
                style={[{
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.text
                }, this.props.style]}>
                {this.props.children}
            </RNText>
        )
    }
}

export default Text;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I got this error : Type arguments can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8011)

Comment: I just solved it using this website https://www.typescriptlang.org/play .  But now I have a Text.d.ts file and Text.js file. Is there any way to solve it in 1 file?

Comment: @SickRanchez you can by change file extension js to ts

Comment: I already tried that but it throws lots of errors. I am not very familiar with TS yet and I don't know how the syntax should be. I also couldn't find any online converters from js to ts. I'm a bit stuck

Comment: then you should use Text.d.ts method

Comment: Alright. I will use d.ts method but can you show me how it looks like in just ts? It'd help me a lot