# React Javascript - Visual Studio Code doesn't auto-complete object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React HOC that propagate an instance of a class to the children.

```
import React from "react";

import ObjContext from "../../context/Obj/ObjContext";

const withObj = (Component) => (props) => (
  <ObjContext.Consumer>
    {(obj) => <Component {...props} obj={obj} />}
  </ObjContext.Consumer>
);

export default withObj;
```

Now, if in one of the child, I start coding, my code editor (VS Code Studio) doesn't display the properties of the object.

> When I do `props.obj.`   the editor doesn't show me all the stuff which is inside the object.

Instead, if I do const `obj = new Obj()` directly, I can see them.

Why is that? Is impossible to see the data which is inside the object that is propagated from a HOC and received via props?

Any workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like one of my recent problems. I found a workaround but I am not sure if it works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784130/react-native-vs-code-intellisense-for-custom-components

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? There is no way for VSCode to know what the properties of `props.obj` will be unless you have a way to explicitly declare them. JSDoc comments could be another alternative.

Comment: @jered No, I am not using typescript. Will try JSDoc. This stuff sucks, as my object is really complex

Comment: Embrace TypeScript if you can. It's really not hard to get started with, and you can mix it into existing vanilla JS codebases.

Comment: @jered u know any good and complete tutorial for getting pro typescripter in a week?

Comment: Also, I know about the existance of PropTypes. But, if I need to know all the properties of a really long object, defining its "interface" (I imagine its something like that) in a TypeScript module, will help my editor?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the real answer here is TypeScript.
To see how your vs code editor would react with typescript, you can quickly do:

```
// Inside child component:
import Obj from 'path/to/obj'
...
export class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    this.obj: Obj;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.obj = this.pros.obj;
        this.obj.something() // something would be proposed by ide
    }
...
}
```

(Ofc the vs code will growl saying that types are not eligible in a .js file and you'd need .tsx instead, but for the purpose of taking a look at how TS would help with the auto-completion, its fine.